# Rendering bitstring from phoenix view

Tags: elixir, rendering, phoenix-framework, bit, bitstring

I have a bitstring of the form `bitstring = <<18::6,8::4,2::5,16::5,18::6,3000::16,0::4>>`. I want to render but poison or Jason doesn't seem to be rendering. What is the best way to render a bitstring in response like this.

Something like this

```
bits = <<18::6,8::4,2::5,16::5,18::6,3000::16,0::4>>
render(conn, "bits.json", bits: bits)
```

Comment: What do you mean by render? JSON doesn't have a binary data type. What's your expected JSON value?

Comment: So I need to convert into a valid bitstring? How do I convert this into a valid bistring so that it can be parsed again into binary

Comment: What JSON value are you expecting for this? An array of bytes? or perhaps Base64 encoded string?

Comment: Array of bytes actually

Comment: `46` bits cannot be packed into an array of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to encode and then later decode the bitstring, and efficiency of storage is a concern, I'd go with converting the bitstring to a binary using `term_to_binary` and then encoding it as a base-64 string. This will give you a nice compact representation of the bitstring that can later be decoded.

```
defmodule A do
  def encode(bitstring) when is_bitstring(bitstring) do
    bitstring |> :erlang.term_to_binary() |> Base.encode64
  end

  def decode(binary) do
    decoded = binary |> Base.decode64!() |> :erlang.binary_to_term([:safe])
    if is_bitstring(decoded), do: decoded, else: nil
  end
end

IO.inspect encoded = A.encode(<<0::220>>)
IO.inspect A.decode(encoded)
```

Output:

```
"g00AAAAcBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="
<<0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0::size(4)>>
```

You can pass the output of `A.encode` to your JSON encoder and call `A.decode` after decoding using the JSON decoder.

Comment: This answer is perfect

Answer (score 1):

One cannot convert `46` bits into byte array. AFAICT, there are two most natural options here.

One might use the array with a binary representation of the value:

```rb
for << <<c::1>> <- <<18::6,8::4,2::5,16::5,18::6,3000::16,0::4>> >>, do: c    
#⇒ [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
#   0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

or one might use the binary with the above joined:

```rb
(for << <<c::1>> <- <<18::6,8::4,2::5,16::5,18::6,3000::16,0::4>> >>, do: c)
|> Enum.join()
#⇒ "0100101000000101000001001000001011101110000000"
```